# Как каждый день проверять время на попадание в интервал между часами начала и конца?

Tags: delphi, время

Мне требуется выполнять некий код в программе в определенные часы.
К примеру ставим диапазон 20 - 12. Это значит что код будет выполняться каждую минуту с 20 часов вечера (каждого дня) по 12 часов дня (каждого следующего дня).

Я пробовал использовать `InRange` в таймере для этих целей, но оно начинает работать неправильно если есть переход на следующие сутки.

К примеру сделать с 7 утра по 8 вечера:

```
if InRange(strtoint(FormatDateTime('hh', now)), strtoint('07'), strtoint('20'))
```

И все работает. Но, если я хочу скажем с 8 вечера по 12 часов дня, то такой код уже не работает...
диапазон')

```
var
  now_h:string;
  dtCurrent,dtFrom,dtTo:TDateTime;
  range_hour_begin,range_hour_end:string;
begin
  range_hour_begin:='20';
  range_hour_end:='15';

  now_h:=FormatDateTime('hh', now);
  dtCurrent := Now;

  dtFrom := RecodeHour(dtCurrent, strtoint(range_hour_begin));
  dtTo := RecodeHour(dtCurrent, strtoint(range_hour_end));

  if strtoint(range_hour_end) < strtoint(range_hour_begin)
  then dtTo := IncDay(dtTo);

  if InRange(dtCurrent, dtFrom, dtTo)
  then showmessage('Входит в диапазон')
  else showmessage('Не входит в диапазон');
```

Comment: А почему бы не использовать [`DateTimeInRange`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.DateTimeInRange)? По истечении интервала прибавлять сутки с помощбю [`IncDay`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils.IncDay).

Comment: Тоже вариант , согласен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текущее время попадает в диапазон, если выполнено одно из двух условий:

- Время начала меньше времени окончания (интервал внутри суток), и текущее время внутри диапазона.
- Время начала больше времени окончания (интервал пересекает границу суток), и текущее время либо больше времени начала, либо меньше времени окончания.

Предлагаю уменьшить количество жонглирований строками при помощи `EncodeTime`, и формировать значение типа `TTime`.

Функция `Time` аналог `Now`, но возвращает только время без даты.

```
var tFrom, tTo, tNow: TTime;
...
  tFrom = EncodeTime(strtoint(range_hour_begin), 0, 0, 0);
  tTo = EncodeTime(strtoint(range_hour_end), 0, 0, 0);
...
  tNow = Time;

  if (tFrom <= tTo) and (tFrom <= tNow) and (tNow <= tTo)
     or
     (tFrom  > tTo) and ((tFrom <= tNow) or (tNow <= tTo))
  then showmessage('Входит в диапазон')
  else showmessage('Не входит в диапазон');
```